# MySQL: Conditional Join Not Showing All Data For Calculating Distance Between Lat/Longs

Tags: mysql, sql

**Problem**

I am performing a conditional join using an `if` statement and it is failing to return all of the records I would ideally expect it to return.

Users on my app input a location via an autocomplete input form and select a distance in miles. The hardcoded lat/long coordinates in the query below are the lat/long coords of the location the user inputted in the form (therefore it's dynamic) and the distance is the distance in miles the user inputted (also dynamic).

The query should first check to see if an `at_resources` has a "place served" associated to their resource id within the specified miles. If a resource id **does not have any** location specified in the `at_places_served` table it should use the `zipcode_name` column in the `at_resources` table as a fallback. Also note `zipcode_name` can be `NULL`.

In particular, in the event a resource does not have a places served record it will use their resource table record to calculate the distance.

Below is my code and screenshot of what this particular query returns.

Please let me know if you would like me to provide you with sample MySQL data so you know what the tables look like or explain anything further.

Thank you and regards.

**Code**

```
SELECT resource.id id, resource.resource_name_line_1, resource.resource_name_line_2, resource.resource_handle, zips.zip_display_name, zips.lat, zips.long,
MIN((3959 * acos(cos(radians(42.3122)) * cos(radians(zips.lat))
* cos(radians(zips.long) - radians(-71.1947)) + sin(radians(42.3122))
* sin(radians(zips.lat))))) AS distance
FROM at_resources resource
JOIN at_resources_places_served places_served
ON places_served.resource_id = resource.id
JOIN at_zip_mapping zip_mapping
ON IF(places_served.resource_id IS NOT NULL, zip_mapping.zip_name_id = places_served.zipcode_name_id AND places_served.active = 1, zip_mapping.zip_name_id = resource.zipcode_name AND resource.active = 1) 
JOIN at_zips zips
ON zips.id = zip_mapping.zip_id
GROUP BY resource.id
HAVING distance < 25
ORDER BY distance, resource.resource_name_line_1 ASC
```

**Here is a SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c17155/1**

**Query**
[image]

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, but `places_served.resource_id` cannot be `NULL` because it is being used as a join key.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I added a SQL Fiddle to show you my table structure. I am trying to calculate the distance between two lat/longs (the hardcoded one is user provided) and the rest are looked up in the database. First it should check to see if a resource has a place served associated with them in the at_places_served table that is within the specified distance otherwise it should check the at_resources table to see if that zipcode is within the distance.

Comment: Can we see some data and a desired result?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
   resource.id id, 
   resource.resource_name_line_1, 
   resource.resource_name_line_2, 
   resource.resource_handle, 
   zips.zip_display_name, 
   zips.lat, zips.long,
   MIN((3959 * acos(cos(radians(42.3122)) * cos(radians(zips.lat))
        * cos(radians(zips.long) - radians(-71.1947)) +
         sin(radians(42.3122))
        * sin(radians(zips.lat))))) AS distance
FROM at_resources resource
LEFT JOIN at_resources_places_served places_served
  ON places_served.resource_id = resource.id
LEFT JOIN at_zip_mapping zip_mapping_by_id
  ON 
     places_served.resource_id IS NOT NULL AND 
     zip_mapping_by_id.zip_name_id = places_served.zipcode_name_id AND 
     places_served.active = 1 
LEFT JOIN at_zip_mapping zip_mapping_by_zipcode
  ON 
     places_served.resource_id IS NULL AND 
     zip_mapping_by_zipcode.zip_name_id = resource.zipcode_name AND 
        resource.active = 1 
JOIN at_zips zips
   ON places_served.resource_id IS NOT NULL AND zips.id = zip_mapping_by_id.zip_id
JOIN at_zips zips_by_zipcode
   ON places_served.resource_id IS NULL AND 
      zips_by_zipcode.id = zip_mapping_by_zipcode.zip_id
GROUP BY resource.id
HAVING distance < 25
ORDER BY distance, resource.resource_name_line_1 ASC
```

**Update:**

I add more conditional join with at_zips if places_served.resource_id IS NOT NULL and if they are not.

Comment: I added a SQL Fiddle as well as more question details. I tried your query; however, I get this error: "Unknown column 'zip_mapping.zip_id' in 'on clause'"

Comment: This result is pretty close to what I am looking for...however, I still don't get back results from the at_resources table for resources that don't have places served associated to their id but have a zipcode_name associated to them and fall within the distance. I updated the question details above to provide more info. Basically the at_resources table zipcode_name should be used as a fallback if no places served records for resource. Thank you!

Comment: This query with your latest update does not return any results for me.

Comment: Sorry, it is quite hard for me to figure out without sample input data and output you expected.

Answer (score 0):

What you are after are some Left Joins: This will add nulls to row if it doesn't have something to join to instead of omitting it:

```
SELECT  resource.id id ,
    resource.resource_name_line_1 ,
    resource.resource_name_line_2 ,
    resource.resource_handle ,
    zips.zip_display_name ,
    zips.lat ,
    zips.long ,
    MIN(( 3959 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(42.3122)) * COS(RADIANS(zips.lat))
                      * COS(RADIANS(zips.long) - RADIANS(-71.1947))
                      + SIN(RADIANS(42.3122)) * SIN(RADIANS(zips.lat))) )) AS distance
FROM at_resources resource
LEFT JOIN at_resources_places_served places_served ON places_served.resource_id = resource.id
LEFT JOIN at_zip_mapping zip_mapping    ON IF(places_served.resource_id IS NOT NULL, zip_mapping.zip_name_id = places_served.zipcode_name_id AND places_served.active = 1, zip_mapping.zip_name_id = resource.zipcode_name AND resource.active = 1) 

LEFT JOIN at_zips zips ON zips.id = zip_mapping.zip_id
GROUP BY resource.id
HAVING distance < 25
ORDER BY distance
, resource.resource_name_line_1 ASC
```

Without test data I cant really test if your ON statements look ok, the look good at a glance, and they seem to be doing the job for you, so fingers crossed! If not, try setting up a http://sqlfiddle.com/ for us and we can play with it a bit better

Comment: I added a SQL Fiddle above to my original question. The problem I'm seeing with your solution is it does not perform a lookup on the at_resources table in the event a resource does not have a places served associated with them. The at_places_served is the first table it should check and the at_resources table is a backup for looking up locations.